# Swapping sublists in prolog

Tags: prolog, swap, sublist

I'm searching for a compact predicate to swap sublists of fixed length within a larger list. For example, if sublists have size 3 then

```
[a,t,t,g,c,c]
```

becomes

```
[g,c,c,a,t,t]
```

I ended up with the following program:

```
dna_sub(A,B,X,Xe) :-
    append(A1,_,A),
    length(A1,Xe),
    append(B1,B,A1),
    length(B1,X).

dna_swap(A,B,X,Xe,Y,Ye) :-
    length(A, Size),
    dna_sub(A,Part1, 0, X),
    dna_sub(A,Part2, X, Xe),
    dna_sub(A,Part3, Xe, Y),
    dna_sub(A,Part4, Y, Ye),
    dna_sub(A,Part5, Ye, Size),
    append(Part1, Part4, Tmp),
    append(Tmp, Part3, Tmp2),
    append(Tmp2, Part2, Tmp3),
    append(Tmp3, Part5, B).

dna_swap(A,B) :-
    length(A, Size),
    Limit is Size - 3,
    between(0,Limit, X),
    Xe is X + 3,
    Xs is Xe,
    between(Xs, Size, Y),
    Ye is Y + 3,
    dna_swap(A,B,X,Xe,Y,Ye).
```

It seems to be working. For example, the following query:

```
dna_swap([t,a,g,t,g,c], L).
```

Obtains the correct answer in L.

Anyway, as you can see, it's very verbose. Is there a better way?

**Edit**

This seems to work a lot better:

```
dna_swap(A,B) :-
    append(Left1, [X1,X2,X3|Right1], A),
    append(Left2, [Y1,Y2,Y3|Right2], Right1),
    append(Left1, [Y1,Y2,Y3|Left2], Tmp),
    append(Tmp, [X1,X2,X3|Right2], B).
```

Comment: How is the length of sublists  provided??In your example [a,t,t,g,c,c] were do you pass the information that sublists have length 3?if you had  [a,t,t,g,c,c,a,b,c] which has 3 sublists of length 3 how do you swap them ?

Comment: @kentilla - a (little) obvious semplification is abolish `Xs` and use `Xe` (`between(Xe, Size, Y)`), but... this instruction... shouldn't it be `between(Xe, Limit, Y)` ?

Comment: @coder it is hard coded in dna_swap/2, where there are +3 and -3.

Comment: @yes but what I'm asking is you want always to be swap +3, could you give what the output should be for example with [a,t,t,g,c,c,a,b,c] ?

Comment: @max66 thanks for your hints. I'd like to know if i'm approaching the problem incorrectly, i.e. there is some trick i'm not aware of to get the job done with few lines, using a built in predicate or such.

Comment: @coder for example [a,t,t] swapped with [a,b,c], or [t,t,g] with [c,a,b] or [c,c,a] with [a,t,t], and so on.

Comment: @kentilla - I'm not a Prolog expert so I can't say if your Prolog approach is correct (but I find strange you `dna_sub/2`; work (if I'm not wrong) but I suspect that is short but inefficient). About your question on Stack Overflow... I think I've understand what do you ask but I'm not sure; I suggest you to modify it to respond to the Coders's questions; by example... exactly... which values do you expect for `L` from `dna_swap([a,t,t,g,c,c,a,b,c], L)` ?

Comment: Moreover, what happens if your list length is not a multiple of 3? Would e.g. [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] <-> [1,5,6,7,2,3,4] also be allowed?

Answer (score 1):

```
sublists(List,Count,A,B) :-
    length(A,Count),
    append(A,B,List).

swap(List,Count,SwappedList) :-
    sublists(List,Count,A,B),
    append(B,A,SwappedList).
```

Hope this is what you are looking for:

```
4 ?- swap([a,b,c,d],2,S).
S = [c, d, a, b].
```